# Position Legend for Bode Plots

Tags: plotting, legending, control-systems

I am having a problem placing my legend inside a bode plot (magnitude or phase - any would do). I cannot find any command that lets me do so.

My command for bode plot is

```
BodePlot[TF[2 \[Pi] s], {0.001, 100}, 
PhaseRange -> {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Thickness[0.008], Thickness[0.005]}, 
GridLines -> Automatic, 
PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalP]\), \(1\)]\)",
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalP]\), \(2\)]\)", 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalP]\), \(3\)]\)"}, 
PlotLabel -> {"Impulse Response Function \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[ScriptCapitalP]\), \(i\)]\)(s)", ""}, 
FrameLabel -> {{"Frequency [Hz]", 
"Magnitude [dB]"}, {"Frequency [Hz]", "Phase [deg]"}}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontSize -> 20}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

Here, **TF** is a *TransferFunctionModel*.

**I want to put the legends inside the bode plot environment rather than it occurring on the side.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `PlotLegends` option in `BodePlot` is not used to label the magnitude and phase. Instead, you use `PlotLegends` whenever you plot more than one function in the same call of `BodePlot`. If you want to label the magnitude and phase plots, you can use `PlotLabel`:

```
BodePlot[
  {
   TransferFunctionModel[{{{20}}, 20 + s}, s], 
   TransferFunctionModel[{{{10}}, 15 + 2 s}, s]
  },
  PlotLegends -> {
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalP]\), \(1\)]\)",
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[ScriptCapitalP]\), \(2\)]\)"
  },
  PlotLabel -> {"Magnitude Plot", "Phase Plot"}
]
```

*Edit*
If you want a legend inside of the plot, you can use `Epilog` and `LineLegend`:

```
BodePlot[
  TransferFunctionModel[{{{20}}, 20 + s}, s], 
  Epilog -> {
    Inset[LineLegend[{Blue}, {"Amplitude"}], {1, -15}], 
    Inset[LineLegend[{Blue}, {"Phase"}], {1, -60}]
  }
]
```

Comment: I may not have been clear with my question. I want to put the legends inside the bode plot environment rather than it occurring on the side. Thanks for the interest though!

Comment: Ah, I am sorry for misunderstanding you. In that case, you should use `Epilog` and `LineLegend`. Let me update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Great job...thanks :)